# JavaScript Interference

Tags: javascript

Here is my `<head>` + `<body>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.septa.org/site/js/jquery-1.4.2.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert(){
var linkElement = document.getElementById("BackButton");
var linkElementLnk = document.getElementById("BackButtonlnk");
var loc_array = document.location.href.split('/');

if (loc_array[loc_array.length-3] == "m")
{
  linkElementLnk.style.display = 'none';
}
if (loc_array[loc_array.length-3] == "maps" || loc_array[loc_array.length-2] == "stations" || loc_array[loc_array.length-3] == "stations" )
{
  linkElementLnk.style.display = 'block';
  var newT = document.createTextNode("Stations & Maps");
}
if (loc_array[loc_array.length-2] == "w" || loc_array[loc_array.length-2] == "s" || loc_array[loc_array.length-2] == "h" )
{
  linkElementLnk.style.display = 'block';
  var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-2])));
}
else if (loc_array[loc_array.length-3] != "m")
{
  linkElementLnk.style.display = 'block';
  if (loc_array[loc_array.length-1] == "index.html" || loc_array[loc_array.length-1] == "index.shtml" || loc_array[loc_array.length-1] == "")
  {
  var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-3])));
  }
  else
  {
  var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-2])));
  }
}
linkElement.appendChild(newT);
}
function capWords(str){ 
   var words = str.split(" "); 
   for (var i=0 ; i < words.length ; i++){ 
      var testwd = words[i]; 
      var firLet = testwd.substr(0,1); 
      var rest = testwd.substr(1, testwd.length -1) 
      words[i] = firLet.toUpperCase() + rest 
   }
   return words;
} 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.septa.org/site/js/qTip.js"></script>
<style>
div#qTip {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  display: none;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #FFF;
  font: bold 9px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="insert();">
```

When I have the `onload="insert();"` in my `<body>` it keeps the jQuery tool tip from working. Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked over the code at : http://www.septa.org/site/js/qTip.js 
The one you are including above.

Guess what I found? Jackpot!

```
window.onload = function () {
    tooltip.init ();
}
```

So when you add your own function into the body tag it overrides the tooltip function.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove onload="insert();" and use jquery ready.

```
$(document).read(function() {
  insert();
});
```

and when you use jquery insted

```
var linkElement = document.getElementById("BackButton");
```

use

```
var linkElement = $('#BackButton');
```

insted

```
inkElementLnk.style.display = 'block';
```

use jquery

```
inkElementLnk.css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some kind of race condition is occurring? It's difficult to say without seeing all the code, but why not do `insert()` when the document is ready, since your using jQuery already?

```
$(function () {
    insert();
});
```

In light of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346817/javascript-interference/3346873#3346873), you could avoid this in future by doing something like

```
var oldLoad = window.onLoad || function(){};
window.onLoad = function() {    
    // new functionality

    oldLoad();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delay before calling `inside`. In the below code it'll get called after half a sec:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(insert, 500);
});
```

This will make sure that the tooltip init function will be called *before* your own code.